# How to search and combine several sheets in Excel?

Tags: excel

I am trying to do an Excel sheet to do some statistics about athletes in world cup competitions.

I have a worksheet on excel for every competition, plus one for the overall result after the season (which thus has a list of every athlete that competed at least once).

The worksheets have the name of the location where the competition happened. Eg: PARIS.

I have one more sheet, named "Athletes". what I want to do there is:
for every athlete appearing in the "overall" list, I want the columns after the name to be filled with the results in every location the athlete completed in.

For example

Name Paris London LA Berlin

Amoros 1 5 / 7

Bilboni 2 43 3 12

To find "1", I want excel to search the sheet "Paris" for "Amoros" and extract the ranking in the row it finds "Amoros".

Let's say it finds "Amoros" in cell L57, then the corresponding ranking to extract will be in K57. "/" indicates Amoros didn't compete in LA.

I am using Excel 2016 on a Mac.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you data is set up starting in A1 you would use INDEX/MATCH with INDIRECT to set the sheet:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("'" & B$1 & "'!$K:$K"),MATCH($A1,INDIRECT("'" & B$1 & "'!$L:$L"),0)),"/")
```

This formula would go in B2 and be copied over and down the dataset.

Comment: Hi thanks alot. It worked with MATCH only, in fact. I didn't know MATCH existed ;-)
So =MATCH($B2;PARIS!$B$1:$B$50;0) did it, in the end.